# Maven: inheriting from an aggregator

Tags: inheritance, maven, module, aggregation

I have the following situation: There is projectA which has multiple components:

projectA/component1
projectA/component2

there is a projectA/pom.xml which aggregates ('modules' tag) those 2 components to build projectA.

now, projectB depends on projectA.component1, and my goal is to build projectB using one command only, without manually building projectA first. There is one way which works - let projectB/pom.xml inherit from projectA/component1/pom.xml (where packaging is pom).

But when things get larger, I would ideally want projectB to inherit from projectA/pom.xml and use whatever components projectA consists of. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would put project A and B in a super-project (Project 0 ?) which aggregates them both

```
Project 0
|
|-ProjectA
| |--component1
| |--component2
|
|-ProjectB
```

You can run

`mvn install --projects=ProjectB --also-make`

from the root of project 0; it won't built component2 because ProjectB doesn't depend on it, but it will build component1.

Comment: Logically it is not necessary that ProjectA and ProjectB are related. For e.g., ProjectA can be a collection of utilities (string libraries, some generic graph data structures etc.) and projectB might be some server implementation which requires utilities. <br/>

In that scenario this looks like a bit of a hack to relate them by putting them into one super-project. <br/>

Also, my biggest goal is to decrease the number of steps for building a project. Preventing extra stuff from getting built is secondary. Achieving both together would be awesome. <br/>

Comment: Well, they *are* related, in that ProjectB depends on ProjectA. I assume they both live in the same source code repository.

Comment: Think of very large scale - say Google. E.g. take 5 products - ads, search, news, blogger, images, say in a repository googlecode/ads, googlecode/search etc. News uses code from search (for news search) and images (for image resizing).  Then there are tools like bigtable, mapreduce which are in googlecode/bigtable and googlecode/mapreduce. There is utilities, machine learning stuff etc.  What you are proposing is a monolithic googlecode/pom.xml which contains a huge number of "aggregated groups".    I need maven to allow adding a path to compile from if it can't find the jar (or equivalent).

Comment: Anyways, I think using a continuous build process (like Hudson) to create a global repository for all developers is the only solution - when using maven.

Comment: You need to distinguish between *source* and *binary* artifacts. Binaries should be compiled once (per version) and put in a global repository such as Nexus.